# Different image take by camera and image copy from PC to iPhone

Tags: ios, uiimage, zxing

I have written an QR Code Scanner application for iOS using `ZXingObjC library`. I scaned QR  code using `camera (AVCaptureSession)`, it worked very well. But when I scan UIImage get from camera roll (UIImagePickerViewController), I am not able to scan some QRCode. I debug, I know that library is not detecting correct position of left bottom corner.

So, my question is `" Is there any difference between image take by camera and image copy from PC to iPhone".`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the answer for my question, but I find a solution for my problem. I don't know "Is there any difference between image take by camera and image copy from PC to iPhone". But now I can scan the UIImage (which before this time, I can't scan). My solution is ROTATE this UIImage a small angle. I don't know that is my error or ZXingObjC error.
I hope it can help who has same problem.